# Install multiple versions of Eclipse in the same place

Tags: eclipse

I have downloaded Eclipse Javascript and Eclipse PDT. Now I want to install them in one place, because I want to get both features in one place.

How can I do this?

I know one way is to install (unpack) one of the above and add the other via Install New Software on the help menu, but I can't do online installation due to my internet connection constraints.

I am running Debian 6.0.1a, i386.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(*) Unpack both packages to disk
(*) From one of the packages, go to: Help->Install New Software->Add->Local
(*) Browse to the other package, and select the folder: eclipse->p2->profileRegistry->
(*) Install the software.

Alternatively you can use Marketplace client to find and install the plugins from the other package.

Comment: G.R.: This worked, but the path was: eclipse/p2/org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine/profileRegistry/epp.package.xxxx.profile where xxxx is the name of the package like javascript or cpp.

Answer (score 0):

This **should** work:  Copy the features and plugins directories from one installation to the other. You will get warnings about many files being duplicates that you can ignore. I would then run eclipse -clean on the result just to be safe.

Please test this on a throwaway Eclipse installation first, because I have not tried it myself, but having written Eclipse plugins and RCP apps, I have some confidence that it will work.

Comment: I copied and replaced the files, but on the New Project window, it only shows the base installation project templates.

Answer (score 0):

[Eclipse 3.7 M7](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/S-3.7M7-201104280848/eclipse-news-M7.html#Platform) has a feature to do what you want exactly.